# Problem in login of admin panel

Tags: magento-1.9, admin-panel, change-password

Actually, I entered the correct details of user name and password in admin panel in localhost. After entered the details, it shows invalid details.

How do I login to the admin panel in localhost.

Comment: Please check the answer. plz let me know if that useful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 ways to clear this issue.

**Way 1:**

You can update password from phpmyadmin. Go to table "admin_user" and run this sql:

```
UPDATE `admin_user` SET `password` = MD5('YourPassowrd') WHERE `username` = 'USERNAME';
```

**Way 2:**

Go to `app->etc->local.xml` file and check the user name and password details.

**Way 3:**

1. Delete the local.xml file and run the website.
2. Then that will ask for the database, user and password. Enter your details and work.

Don't worry, No problem with these ways.

Answer (score 3):

You can update passoword from phpmyadmin. Go to table "admin_user" and run this sql:

```
UPDATE `admin_user` SET `password` = MD5('YourPassowrd') WHERE `username` = 'USERNAME';
```

Check and let us know.

Answer (score 1):

You can change your password in the admin_user table in your database..
The Password in MD5() format so you use the MD5() function when change your Password..

```
UPDATE `admin_user` SET `password` = MD5('YourPassowrd') WHERE `username` = 'USERNAME';
```